# Upload attachment in JIRA using MS bot Framework

Tags: postman, jira, jira-rest-api, bot-emulator

I'm trying to upload an attachment for Jira ticket using Microsoft Bot framework in Nodejs.

I'm calling the attachment Api in Jira using below code snippet:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const fs = require('fs');
const FormData = require('form-data')

dotenv.config();

class attachmentAPI {
    constructor() {
    }
    async uploadJIRAImage(key) {


        let urlString = `https://{jira-site-name}.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/${key}/attachments`;
        console.log(urlString);

        const credentials = process.env.JiraUsername + ":" + process.env.JiraPassword;
        const hash = Buffer.from(credentials).toString('base64');
        const Basic = 'Basic ' + hash;


        let formData = new FormData();
        //Here I want to upload image url from emulator
        **let stream = fs.createReadStream("Image.png");**
        formData.append('file', stream);
        let formHeaders = formData.getHeaders();

        let res = await axios.post(urlString, formData, {
            headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': Basic,
            'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck',
            ...formHeaders
            }
        });

        console.log("Api-Result: ",res)
    }
        

}
exports.attachmentAPI = attachmentAPI;
```

In this way I can now able to upload the image. As it is located in the same folder locally. But I want to upload an image url from emulator, that need to be attached to JIRA ticket.

emulator image uploaded content is in this format:

```
{
name: 'SAP-Logo.png',
contentType: 'image/png',
contentUrl: 'http://localhost:12345/v3/attachments/1b864600-fe77-11eb-bc85-b3c9f4256d99/views/original' 
}
```

How do I successfully send the image Url/path in the above code as formdata that attach the image to Jira ticket?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i would read the `requestify` documentation - nothing to do with bot framework

Comment: if I want to do the same with ServiceNow ticket, (updating ServiceNow ticket with attachment) how can I upload image with content URL in body and make it successful.

Comment: for this I have downloaded the image to a folder and get the image from that path and uploaded it in api as form-data.